# BigQuery convert Month Year column to timestamp or date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table

```
Year_month     amount
08-2021         100
09-2021         200
10-2021         300
```

I want to add a column `Month` to be

```
Year_month   Month         amount
08-2021    01-08-2021         100
09-2021    01-09-2021         200
10-2021    01-10-2021         300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the type of data you have. check below code:

```
with sodata as (
  select '08-2021' as Year_month_string,  PARSE_DATE("%m-%Y", "08-2021") as Year_month_date, 100 amount,
  union all 
  select '09-2021',PARSE_DATE("%m-%Y", "09-2021"), 200
  union all 
  select '10-2021',PARSE_DATE("%m-%Y", "10-2021"), 300
  
)
SELECT Year_month_string,FORMAT('01-%s',Year_month_string) as using_format,FORMAT_DATE("%d-%m-%Y", Year_month_date) as using_format_date,amount from sodata
```

output

| **Row** | **Year_month** | **using_format** | **using_format_date** | **amount** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08-2021 | 01-08-2021 | 01-08-2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 09-2021 | 01-09-2021 | 01-09-2021 | 200 |
| 3 | 10-2021 | 01-10-2021 | 01-10-2021 | 300 |

To see more details about the functions used please go to this links:

- [Format (string)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string)
- [Format Date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parse date function

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%m-%Y", "08-2021")
```